# How to map dynamic path parameter in Haproxy

Tags: haproxy

I am trying to pass dynamic value based on user_id in haproxy for my java Rest Services.

localhost:/AAA/BBB/{userid}

Following Statement are example

localhost:/AAA/BBB/1

localhost:/AAA/BBB/2

localhost:/AAA/BBB/3

I want to pass it through haproxy . I have following configuration..

```
global
    log /dev/log    local0
    log /dev/log    local1 notice
    chroot /var/lib/haproxy
    stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin
    stats timeout 30s
    user haproxy
    group haproxy
    daemon

    # Default SSL material locations
    ca-base /etc/ssl/certs
    crt-base /etc/ssl/private

    # Default ciphers to use on SSL-enabled listening sockets.
    # For more information, see ciphers(1SSL).
    ssl-default-bind-ciphers kEECDH+aRSA+AES:kRSA+AES:+AES256:RC4- SHA:!kEDH:!LOW:!EXP:!MD5:!aNULL:!eNULL
```

defaults

```
     log     global
     mode    http
     option  httplog
     option  dontlognull
     timeout connect 5000
     timeout client  50000
    timeout server  50000
    errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
    errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
    errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
    errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
    errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
    errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
    errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http
```

frontend http

```
bind *:80    
acl msg-listing-read path_end -i /AAA/BBB/{user_id}
use_backend ppl-be-msg-listing-read-dev if msg-listing-read
```

backend ppl-be-msg-listing-read-dev

```
balance roundrobin
server ppl-msg-listing-read-dev localhost:8080 maxconn 32 check
```

listen stats

```
bind 0.0.0.0:81
stats enable
stats uri /
```

Any idea will be appreciated and Thanks in Advance.

Comment: *"I am trying to pass dynamic value based on user_id in haproxy"* ...what does "based on" mean? You want to pass the same value? Where do you want to "pass" it?  What you are trying to accomplish, and why, are not clear.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I mean i want to pass several different values according to my value i (1,2,3,....)as in localhost:/AAA/BBB/i .
If I am giving  localhost:/AAA/BBB/1 and mapping same in haproxy then it is working fine. but i want that my mapping should work for all values after "/AAA/BBB/"instead of fixed value.

Comment: So, `path_reg -i ^/AAA/BBB/.+` perhaps?  You can get a more accurate match by replacing `.+` with a more correct pattern.

Comment: thanks Sir a lot @Michael-sqlbot.. it worked.. +1 if i had....